# javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Tags: java, spring-boot

this is my reference project

```
https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration
```

and I am using spring boot 2 and i want complete control of my MVC.
so i am using `@EnablWebMvc` to disable the auto configuration as follows:-

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.demo" })
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public MvcConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index");
        registry.addViewController("/index");
        registry.addViewController("/loginRememberMe");
        registry.addViewController("/customLogin");
        registry.addViewController("/registration.html");
        registry.addViewController("/registrationCaptcha.html");
        registry.addViewController("/logout.html");
        registry.addViewController("/homepage.html");
        registry.addViewController("/expiredAccount.html");
        registry.addViewController("/badUser.html");
        registry.addViewController("/emailError.html");
        registry.addViewController("/home.html");
        registry.addViewController("/invalidSession.html");
        registry.addViewController("/console.html");
        registry.addViewController("/admin.html");
        registry.addViewController("/successRegister.html");
        registry.addViewController("/forgetPassword.html");
        registry.addViewController("/updatePassword.html");
        registry.addViewController("/changePassword.html");
        registry.addViewController("/users.html");
        registry.addViewController("/qrcode.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(final DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/", "/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        final LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
    }

    // beans

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        final CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    // @Bean
    // public MessageSource messageSource() {
    // final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    // messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    // messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    // messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    // messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    // return messageSource;
    // }


    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(RequestContextListener.class)
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return validator;
    }
```

and my resources folder structure is
[image]

now when i open the application like this:-

```
http://localhost:8888/
```

i expect the index.html page to open. but unfortunately it throws error something like:-

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

i have tried

```
registry.addViewController("/index");
registry.addViewController("/index.html");
```

nothing works.

Comment: can you change these two line of code and recheck : registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/index.html");

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@EnableWebMvc` above `MvcConfig`

and change try these method with the two line changed, others the same:

```
@Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html"); 
        registry.addViewController("/index.html");
        // add other lines

    }
```